# jQuery ajax php rename part of a file name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, rename

In the frontend i offer the user to rename any of his images. This is done via javascript prompt to get the new name, jQuery ajax and php. When file is renamed it must take effect on 2 files as you see in the links below. `1` in the url is dynamic. It's the user id. The thing is i only want to replace the `product` in the filename and not the `_1317804260` that comes after it. In the second link we have `thumb_` in front of the file name. So again we only want to replace the `product` with the new rename. Working on this, it Seems like i need to use explode() many times to get the job done. Is there an easier way to do this.

```
http://domain.com/userfiles/1/images/product_1317804260.gif
http://domain.com/userfiles/1/images/thumbnails/thumb_product_1317804260.gif
```

So basically if a new name is `newname` the final output of the file should be

```
newname_1317804260.gif
thumb_newname_1317804260.gif
```

Comment: Do you want the result to have the entire URL or only the last part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$oldName = "http://domain...product_userid.gif";

$newName = "what the user entered";

$parts = explode('/', $oldName);
$user_path = $parts[3] . '/' . $parts[4]; // it will contain userfiles/1

$parts = explode("_", $oldName);

$product_name = $new_name . "_" . end($parts);
$thumb_name   = "thumb_" . $product_name;
```

Comment: This will work. but in that case i will also need this from the url `/userfiles/1/`. What's a good way to get that

Comment: I've updated my answer with that info. That was the reason I asked you before if you only need the last part or more.

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
var tmpName = "product_1317804260.gif".split("_")
var newName = "newname" + "_" + tmpName[1]
```

PHP:

```
$tmpName = explode("_", "product_1317804260.gif");
$newName = "newname" . "_" . $tmpName[1];
```

Comment: What is a filename contains allot of underscores. How do we tell it to look for the last one.

Comment: Then use tmpName[tempName.length]

Comment: Thanks, In that case i will also need to get portion of the path. I tried split like this, but it doesn't work. Why is that . `var $x = '/1/images/Oil_and_gas_icon.gif';
alert($x.split("/")[0]);
`

Comment: Element zero comes before the first slash, which is empty.

Comment: alert($x.split("/")[0]) = "1" for me